# Get purged field value after the model is saved

Tags: octobercms

There is a purged field (checkbox) in create form (backend). I don't want to save the field values to table of this model, therefore I added _ (underscore) to the name of this field. It works.

But I need to save these field values to another table. Just table, not model.

I found `getOriginalPurgeValue($attr)` method but how to implement it in `afterCreate()` function? Or there is another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved!

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
   ...

   public function afterCreate()
   {
      // so I can access purged the field value
      $val = $this->getOriginalPurgeValue('_extras');
   }

   protected $purgeable = ['_extras'];
}
```